# unable to show alertdailog.builder?

Tags: android, dialog

```
final ViewGroup layout_order = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(
                        Menus.this).inflate(R.layout.ex, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder_order = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Menus.this);
                builder_order.setView(layout_order);


                Enumeration e = orderDataHT.keys();
                Object obj;
                obj = e.nextElement();
                String quantity = (String) obj;
                String instruction = (String) orderDataHT.get(obj);
                System.out.println(quantity);
                System.out.println(instruction);

                setContentView(R.layout.ex);
                 builder_order.setView(layout_order);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantitytext1);
                tv.setText(quantity, BufferType.NORMAL);
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructiontext);
                tv1.setText(instruction, BufferType.NORMAL);


                 builder_order.show();
```

Comment: Try to add some more detail and you'll get a faster answer! What is the actual error? What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void alert(String message)
    {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
        .setMessage(message)  
         .setTitle("Warning!!!")  
          .setCancelable(true)
               .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,  
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}  
           })  
        .show();    
    }
```

it's function for example, how im using alert..  call :  alert("message");

Comment: i m reading the data from one alert-dialog box ,i store the data in hash-table and i want to retrieve the data which the user entered in another dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog ds;   
  public void exampleDialog()  
        {


         sd = new Dialog(yourClassName.this);
         mainW = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
         mainW.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         // in mainW u can add buttons, TextViews, and other what u want .
         sd.setContentView(mainW);
         sd.setTitle("Download ");
         //here code what you want for example
          TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                   text.setText("some text");
               mainW.addView(text);
         sd.setCancelable(true);
         sd.show();
}
```

hope im right understand u.